# android studio showing control as text

Tags: java, android, xml

Android studio not showing the controls from 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0' properly even if i added it in my build.gradle file

i have already tried setting AppTheme in my styles.xml to 'Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar' and tried multiple rebuilds

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

here the 'android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout' just shows as android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  in the preview

[this is what shows in the preview][1]

[image: a busy cat]

here's my **gradle.build** file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.alto.alizer.altovpn"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Hey @Alizer can you try Invalidate/Cache Restart. Not sure but hope this will work. Also which AS you are using ?

Comment: to improve your post, please share code and not images ;)

Comment: @AJay i  already tried that, I am using version  3.1.3

Comment: @Alizer latest stable AS is 3.4.1. So you might be want to update Android studio and that'll mostly solve this issue

Comment: ok ill try and see if it resolves the problem